# Ubuntu 20.04 stuck on log in screen

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, login

When I attempt to log into my Ubuntu 20.04 virtual machine, I type in my password the screen goes black then goes straight back to the log in screen again. To check if my password is incorrect I enter no password and it shows incorrect password as we expect.
I can access the terminal using:

```
Ctrl + Alt + F1
```

And typing in my username and password. Is there anyway to access my desktop without losing my data?

Thanks in advance!